# Array Index Out Of Bounds when S4 initiating PE

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I am now trying to add a simple PE into my app. This PE extends AbstractPE and overrides output method.(doing nothing)
I also revised the xml file, adding a bean, like following:

```
  <bean id="rogerpe" class="cnu.roger.FPActor.RogerPE">                                                                                                                                       
        <property name="keys">                                                                                                                                                                
                <list>                                                                                                                                                                        
                        <value>RawTransaction *</value>                                                                                                                                       
                </list>                                                                                                                                                                       
        </property>                                                                                                                                                                           
  </bean>
```

But, when I was trying to run the platform. Some exception occurs.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Could not instantiate bean class [cnu.roger.FPActor.RogerPE]: 
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:115)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:61)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:877)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:338)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:351)
    at io.s4.processor.OverloadDispatcherGenerator.generate(OverloadDispatcherGenerator.java:209)
    at io.s4.processor.AbstractPE.<init>(AbstractPE.java:126)
    at cnu.roger.FPActor.RogerPE.<init>(RogerPE.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:100)
    ... 18 more
```

This PE's code:

```
package cnu.roger.FPActor;                                                                                                                                                                    

import java.util.Collections;                                                                                                                                                                 
import java.util.List;                                                                                                                                                                        

import io.s4.processor.AbstractPE;                                                                                                                                                            

class RogerPE extends AbstractPE                                                                                                                                                              
{                                                                                                                                                                                             
        @Override                                                                                                                                                                             
        public void output()                                                                                                                                                                  
        {                                                                                                                                                                                     
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                                                                                                                                            

        }                                                                                                                                                                                     
}
```

I am confusing now. I do not know which array it means.
Any help is appreciated!

In the OverloadDispatcherGenerator.java

```
InstructionHandle returnInstruction = il.append(InstructionFactory.createReturn(Type.VOID));                                                                                          

for (int i = 0; i < targetInstructions.size(); i++) {                                                                                                                                 
    branchInstructions.get(i).setTarget(targetInstructions.get(i));                                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                                                                     

branchInstructions.get(branchInstructions.size() - 1)                                                                                                                                 
                  .setTarget(returnInstruction);                                                                                                                                      

for (BranchInstruction gotoInstruction : gotoInstructions) {                                                                                                                          
    gotoInstruction.setTarget(returnInstruction);                                                                                                                                     

}
```

the 209 line is : branchInstructions.get....

Comment: Show us the code for `RogerPE` and an answer will surely follow :-)

Comment: This exception still occurs, even without constructor.

Comment: Show us the code for AbstractPE and I'll fix the problem.

Comment: The exception occurs at io.s4.processor.OverloadDispatcherGenerator.generate(OverloadDispatcherGenerator.java:209), show me the code at that point.

Comment: I appended the code there. :-)

Comment: @Bloodwolf I've appended the code.

Comment: @Roger, maybe i have fixed your problem.

Comment: @Bloodwolf I may add an "if" to check if it is 0. Much thx for you reply! I would tell if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error code is:

```
branchInstructions.get(branchInstructions.size() - 1)                                                                                                                                 
              .setTarget(returnInstruction);
```

if branchInstructions.size() == 0, then branchInstructions.size() - 1 get -1, but -1 is an invalid index.

Comment: But I do not know what this if statement may cause. I hope it can work well. :-)

Comment: Don't worry, the if statement doesn't have side effect.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you need to make your call to the `super()` constructor **first**.

Otherwise you are working with an object that hasn't been fully initialized. This will probably fix your issue.

Secondly, why create an empty `List<String>` and convert it if all you really want is an empty String array?

```
String[] sa = new String[0];
```

Comment: But after I removed all the constructor. This exception still exist.

Comment: I do not think it is the keys. The stack shows that the exception occurs when the super method invoked. That is why I put it latter.

Comment: I removed the whole constructor and this exception still occurs. :-)